# Spark Persist and UnPersist

Tags: apache-spark

```
 Dataset<Row> Data_one = spark.read().format("csv").option("header","true").load("src/main/resources/exams/students.csv");
        System.out.println("Before persist");
        Data_one.show();
        Data_one.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY());
        System.out.println("After persist");
        Data_one.show();
        Data_one.unpersist();
        System.out.println("After unpersist");
        Data_one.show();
```

The data frame is printing even after unpresist.
Just got confused when the dataframe will unpersist.

Comment: just Google for some doc about caching in Spark to have a basic understanding of its behavior, here for example: [Spark's doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence)

Answer (score 0):

The dataframe will be always printed. Persist just caches it in memory.
When calling any evaluating operations e.g `show`, `head`, etc. on the dataframe, the result will be allways computed.

The difference between persted and persited state is following:
When the dataframe is persisted at some point, a temp result is read from memory. If not, all operations a recomputed again.

In the particular case here "after persist" should take significantly less time to print the dataframe, when "after unpersist"